# Serving static files in Node app from maxCDN

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cdn

Currently we have existing project created with keystone + nunjucks, and all paths to static files looks like `/stc/img/someimage.jpg`, so I don't want to change the links in template. Is it any way to serve them through middleware in node server from maxCDN? something like:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (
    req.path.slice(-5) === '.jpeg' ||
    req.path.slice(-4) === '.jpg' ||
    req.path.slice(-4) === '.svg' ||
    req.path.slice(-4) === '.png' ||
    req.path.slice(-4) === '.gif' ||
    req.path.slice(-4) === '.css' ||
    req.path.slice(-3) === '.js'
  ) {
    req.path = `https://domain.cdn-ssl.com${req.path}`;
  }
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is redirect:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (
    req.path.slice(-5) === '.jpeg' ||
    req.path.slice(-4) === '.jpg' ||
    req.path.slice(-4) === '.svg' ||
    req.path.slice(-4) === '.png' ||
    req.path.slice(-4) === '.gif' ||
    req.path.slice(-4) === '.css' ||
    req.path.slice(-3) === '.js'
  ) {
    res.redirect( `https://domain.cdn-ssl.com${req.path}` );
  } else {
      next();
  }
});
```

Or you can use middleware like `express-http-proxy` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy